# How does mv compare to cp in terms of speed and safety when the transfer is across different filesystems?

Tags: linux, unix

By safety I mean if the transfer gets interrupted, how does that impact the data in both source and dest? Is it also dependent on the specific types of filesystems?

Comment: You may find this answer useful http://superuser.com/questions/94988/is-it-better-to-always-copy-and-delete-rather-than-move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working across filesystems `mv` really has no choice but copying the file, in effect doing whatever `cp` does and then unlinking the original file.

A simple strace shows this:

```
rename("/tmp/file.rand", "./file.rand") = -1 EXDEV (Invalid cross-device link)
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

After this point `mv` reads `65536` bytes at a time from one fd and writes them to the other and does an `unlinkat` at the end.